# Difference between a string and an array of characters

Tags: java

How are these declarations different from each other?

```
String s="MY PROFESSION";
char c[]="MY PROFESSION";
```

What about the memory allocation in each case?

Comment: How can you compare these two if the latter does not even exist?

Comment: A String is a composite object that contains an array of char, plus some other fields.

Comment: a `String` is (an instance of) a class that comes with a lot of String operations. Java has a lot of special language features associated with strings (for example String literals which you used twice). A char array on the other hand lacks those methods, is mutable and has a smaller memory footprint. Allways use String unless you have a very special problem that requires char arrays.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To correct compilation error replace with one of the below `char[]` statement

```
String s = "MY PROFESSION";
char c1[] = "MY PROFESSION".toCharArray();
char c2[] = { 'M', 'Y', ' ', 'P', 'R', 'O', 'F', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'O', 'N' };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("MY PROFESSION");
StringBuffer sbu = new StringBuffer("MY PROFESSION");
```

Following section compares above statement with each other

### String Constant

```
String s="MY PROFESSION";
```

- "MY PROFESSION" is a constant and stored in String pool see [Where does Java's String constant pool live, the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918399/what-type-of-memory-heap-or-stack-string-constant-pool-in-java-gets-stored)
- `s` is immutable i.e content of `String` is intact can not be modified.
- Size/Length of string is fixed (not possible to append)

### Character Array

```
 char c1[]="MY PROFESSION".toCharArray();
 char c2[]={'M', 'Y', ' ', 'P', 'R', 'O', 'F', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'O', 'N'};
```

- `c1` holds copy of String's underlying array (via `System.arraycopy`) and stored in heap space
- `c2` is built on the fly in the stack frame by loading individual character constants
- `c1` & `c2` are mutable i.e content of `Array` can be modified. `c2[0]='B'`
- Size/Length of Array is fixed (not possible to append)

### StringBuilder / StringBuffer

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("MY PROFESSION");
StringBuffer sbu = new StringBuffer("MY PROFESSION");
```

- Both `sb` and `sbu` are mutable. `sb.replace(0, 1, 'B');`
- Both `sb` and `sbu` are stored in heap
- Size/Length can be modified. `sb.append( '!');`
- `StringBuffer`'s methods are synchronised while `StringBuilder`'s methods are not

Answer (score 4):

The first one compiles. The second one doesn't.

A `char[]` is just that: an array of primitive numbers of type char. All it provides is a `length` attribute, and a way to get and set a char at a given index.

A String is an object, of type [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), which has a whole lot of useful methods for manipulating Strings. Internally, it uses a char array.

Another important feature of String is that it's immutable. You can pass a String to any method and be sure that this method won't change the contents of the String. That is not the case with a char array.

Regarding memory, a String consumes some more bytes, but that's generally not what should guide your design decisions: generally, using a char array is not what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html),

```
     String str = "abc";

is equivalent to:

     char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};  //  not 'abc'
     String str = new String(data);
```

More over [String literals are very special in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410)

`String` is backed by a `character` array internally.

Answer (score 1):

An array of characters is mutable, in other words, you can replace a character in an array of characters by overwriting the memory location for that character.

A String is not mutable, in other words, to "replace" a character in a String, you must build a new String with the desired character in place (copying the non-changing parts from the old String).

While this seems simple, it has a profound impact on the ability to share between Thread (and objects).  One String can safely be shared between Threads without extra checks to see if the String is being changed (which might give a Thread an inconsistency read of the String).

Other optimizations are also possible, since Strings cannot mutate, you can rewire equality operations to be "equals by value".  Which means that a "String factory" can return cached copies of the same String, even when two different String objects are requested, because it will become impossible for the two objects to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a primitive type. `String` is a class in which actual data is stored internally as a character array

```
char c[]="MY PROFESSION";
```

will give compilation error.

Character array is the contiguous storage in memory where characters are stored sequentially.

Check out this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283900/what-is-the-difference-between-a-char-array-and-a-string) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> How this declaration differentiate from each other?

Your first line produces a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) instance. Your second line is simply invalid; perhaps you meant:

```
char[] c = {'M', 'Y', ' ', 'P', 'R', 'O', 'F', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'O', 'N'};
```

which creates `char[]` filled with those characters.

> what about its memory allocation?

Storing a string as a `String` is slightly different memory-wise than storing it as a `char[]`. There are similarities though: both are objects, and have the usual object overhead.

However, a `String` holds a `char[]` *internally*, so naturally a `String` consumes more memory. Furthermore, `String` has 3 `int` fields (`offset`, `count` and `hash`) whereas `char[]` has the single `int` field `length`.

For example, storing `"MY PROFESSION"` as a `String`:

- 3 `int` fields: **12** bytes
- `char[]` field: **8** bytes

  - `int` field: **4** bytes
  - object overhead: **8** bytes
  - 13 characters: **26** bytes
- object overhead: **8** bytes

This comes out to about **66** bytes. I say "about" because some of this is dependent on the VM. The corresponding `char[]` of length 10 only consumes **38** bytes, as you can see. The memory difference here is quite negligible so you shouldn't worry about it (and just use a `String`!). It becomes even more insignificant the longer the string you are trying to store becomes.

Answer (score 0):

char is a primitive type while String is a class.
An array of a specified number of strings and strings are a bundle of characters.